# How to derive the HJM drift condition?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to derive the Heath Jarrow Morton drift condition (from Björk, page 298) and this equation is the part that I'm not able to derive:

$$ A(t,T) + \frac{1}{2} ||S(t,T)||^2 = \sum_{i=0}^d S_i(t,T) \lambda_i(t) $$

where
$$
A(t,T) = - \int_t^T \alpha(t,s)ds 
\\ S(t,T) = - \int_t^T \sigma(t,s)ds
\\ \lambda(t) = [\lambda_1(t), ... , \lambda_d(t)]'
$$

The book states that this is obtained from Girsanov Theorem. Can you please help me out in understanding how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the book is attempting, but I provide you with a different proof, which IMHO is quite fast and easy.

For HJM, we have the following dynamics for the instantaneous forward rates:
$
\begin{cases}
df(t,T) = \alpha(t,T) dt + \sigma(t,T) dW_t \\
f(0,T) = f_{\text{mkt}}(0,T)
\end{cases}
$

With such an SDE for f, we have that a ZCB has a dynamics under $\mathbb{Q}$ given by $dp(t,T) = p(t,T)[r(t) + A(t,T)+\frac{\Sigma^2 (t,T)}{2}] + p \Sigma dW_t$, where $A = -\int_{t}^{T} \alpha(t,s) ds$ and $\Sigma = -\int_{t}^{T} \sigma(t,s) ds$.

Since we want to respect NA, the square brakets has to be equal to the riskless rate $r(t)$ which results, after semplification, in $A(t,T)+\frac{\Sigma^2 (t,T)}{2} = 0$ which derived wrt T gives the wanted new drift condition, namely $\alpha(t,T) = \sigma(t,T) \int_{t}^{T}\sigma(t,s) ds$.